# Custom dimension is not storing in Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-ga

I have a 2 tracking ids. one for **Development** environment and another for **Production** environment.

Both are having same custom dimension property called '***dimension1***'.

custom dimension values are storing in **Development** Environment but **Production** Environment is not storing in Google Analytics.

My code below,

```
import ReactGA from "react-ga";

export default {

initializeGA: (trackingId, profileId = null) => {

    ReactGA.initialize(trackingId, {
        debug: true
    });

    ReactGA.pageview("/SplashScreen", { dimension1: profileId });
    ReactGA.set({ dimension1: profileId });
},
pageView: (pageName, profileId) => {

    ReactGA.pageview(pageName, { dimension1: profileId });
},
modalView: (pageName, profileId) => {

    ReactGA.modalview(pageName, { dimension1: profileId });
},
pageEvent: (category, action, label, profileId) => { 

    ReactGA.event({
        category: category,
        action: action,
        label: label
    }, { dimension1: profileId });
} 
}
```

My Custom Dimension

[image]

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

did you set up the entry in GA of your production profile?

Comment: yes. both profile setup done. I use different tracking id for respective environment.